# command line for angular dart

Tags: command-line-interface, angular-dart

I am new to Angular dart and dart in general. It seems like a good framework but I can't seem to be able to find something like the Angular CLI we have for the typescript version.
I tried using - [this](https://github.com/google/angular_cli) but it seems to generate a little older angular dart version (I am currently using Dart 2.0.0-dev and angular 5.0 preview). I have also used [stagehand](https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand) but it just generates a sample app and I cant use it to generate a component or something. Is there any other CLI that might work for AngularDart or maybe some commands. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: There is nothing more recent for AngularDart 5, except what you already found. You can use examples from the Angular repository as a template to get started until better tools become available.

Comment: ok, thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

[`webdev`](https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev) is the new CLI for AngularDart 5+. Right now, it only has a `build` and `serve` command that wrap `build_runner`. We do have plans to integrate with `stagehand` and other tools to provide more functionality, but that will probably come after we release AngularDart v5.